# retain text box and dropdown list values after postback in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

How to get old values after submitting data in asp.net MVC.i am new stuff with MVC i read many articles to reach to this result ,my problem is after clicking search button i lost all values in textbox's and drop down list.

this is my view.cshtml page

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
     {
       <input class="calendarr font" name="Arrival" value="@Request["Arrival"]" readonly type="text" id="Arrival"  onchange="changedDate()">

       <input class="calendarr font" name="Departure" value="@Request["Departure"]" readonly type="text" id="Departure" >

             <select id="Rooms" name="Rooms" class="dropdown">
                 @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.MaximumNumberOfRooms; i++)
                     {
                        <option value="@i @Request["Rooms"]">@i</option>
                            }
                        </select>


                 <select id="Persons" name="Persons" class="dropdown">
                            @for (int j = 1; j <= Model.MaximumNumberOfAdultsPerRoom; j++)
                            {
                                <option value="@j  @Request["Persons"]">@j</option>
                            }
                        </select>                          
                <select id="Childrens" name="Childrens" class="dropdown">
                            @for (int c = 1; c <= Model.MaximumNumberOfChildrenPerRoom; c++)
                            {
                                <option value="@c @Request["Childrens"]">@c</option>
                            }
                        </select>

              <input type="submit" class="btns" value="Search" />

     }
```

And the following code in the HomeController.

```js
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        SessionHelper mysession = new SessionHelper();
      
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index_Post()
        {                                            
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index_Get()
        {
            checkURL();
            pageload();
            string arrival = Request.Form["Arrival"];
            string Departure = Request.Form["Departure"];
            string rooms = Request.Form["Rooms"];
            string Persons = Request.Form["Persons"];
            string Childrens = Request.Form["Childrens"];
            return View(mysession);
        }
}
```

Thanks .

Comment: Pass a model to the view and bind to your view using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods and post back your model

Comment: @StephenMuecke my model is **mysession ** how can i pass it to the view ,example please

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics.

Comment: You got all the help, strongly typed view with HtmlHepers, and post back model from post action method. That's it! You should not expect complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "PostBack" in ASP.MVC. However, here an easy way to do it:

1. Since the parameters you are sending are not sensitive or database-changes, it is more appropriate to have your form as FormMethod.Get instead of FormMethod.Post:

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
   ```
2. In your Index_Get action, type it like this:

   ```
       public class HomeController : Controller
       {
           SessionHelper mysession = new SessionHelper();


           [HttpGet]
           [ActionName("Index")]
           public ActionResult Index_Get(string Arrival, string Departure, string Rooms, string Persons, string Childrens,  )
           {
               checkURL();
               pageload();
               ViewBag.Arrival = Arrival;
               ViewBag.Departure = Departure;
               ViewBag.Rooms = Rooms;
               ViewBag.Persons = Persons;
               ViewBag.Childrens = Childrens;
               return View(mysession);
           }
   }
   ```

As long as your input **name** exists as a parameter within the Index_Get parameters, the parameter will be auto-filled with no need to call Request object. You can also change the parameter type from string to any datatype. However, be careful that other datatypes will not accept null values unless you define them as nullable.

3. On your html change the every field value to a ViewBag object such as:

   `value="@ViewBag.Arrival"`

Hope this helped :)